# CRM 365 Online to Sharepoint Online default folder creation when viewing Document Associated Grid

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

If an entity has been selected for Sharepoint via CRM 365, when viewing a record within CRM, the first time you view the Document Associated Grid (please see image) an automatic folder is created for that record in the format of  (name_guid) in Sharepoint.

Is it possible that the automatic creation of the folder in Sharepoint can be disabled or switched off or another 'default' location may be used as the Document Associated Grid is viewed for the first time?

[image]

Comment: If my Answer was helpful, accept/upvote to help the community finding it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tweak this configuration in any supported OOB way or without code.

What you can do is, instead of waiting for OOB system to create a default folder when the CRM user navigate for each record (ex. Microsoft_xxxx) under the entity (schema name, ex. account) folder of the configured SP location, you can write a C# plugin or custom Workflow or Power Automate (anyway Microsoft planning to retire CRM workflow and moving towards this. aka MS Flow) to create the desired folder under the desired location whenever the new record is created.

[Similar UG discussion thread](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=d266d902-aea3-4b2f-b257-f17006c9762f&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer#bm5721d277-97ad-4353-b232-d369e419853e)

Comment: Hi Arun, many thanks for your answer. If i understand this correctly, once a record is created in CRM, a plugin/custom workflow will run and create the folder structure within Sharepoint? Along with this will a document location need to be created in CRM?

Comment: thanks for the information. One last request, do you have any examples of how you would connect to SharePoint from CRM to create the folder?

Comment: @NDevBrad that’s little tricky, you may find online code samples for connecting SP web api and CRM plugin invoking SP web api, authentication, service bus, etc. you have to put it together. Otherwise try MS Flow/Power Automate which has native connectors to expedite.